# utf-8 file displays doubled characters

Tags: linux, unicode

A generated utf-8 file displays properly in the terminal:
[image]

but not in Firefox or gedit:
[image]

It looks like the characters are doubled with weird ones?

The file:
http://maestric.com/shared/other/2004_10_14.txt

Any idea on what is wrong with it?

Comment: You should show some of the code that's writing to the file

Comment: When I visit the URL above, the web server is NOT sending properly formatted UTF-8 data.  It appears that each valid UTF-8 encoded character sequence has an extra null octet appended to the end of it.  So either the original file itself is corrupted to begin with, or the web server is sending the file data wrong.

Comment: So it's ok in the terminal just because this "extra null octet" is not displayed? If that's the case, you've answered this question and I will have to ask a new one about how to remove it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be UTF-16. Are you sure your locale and terminal is in UTF-8 ?

Did you try an "[od](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/od.1.asp)" on the file, or see it in a hex viewer? Never trust your terminal, you must look at the bytes to be sure.

Eg

```
# od -c -x 2004_10_14.txt  | head
0000000  \0   H  \0   e  \0   u  \0   r  \0   e  \0      \0   d  \0   e
        4800 6500 7500 7200 6500 2000 6400 6500
0000020  \0      \0   d  \0 303 251  \0   b  \0   u  \0   t  \0      \0
        2000 6400 c300 00a9 0062 0075 0074 0020
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the file I was trying to clean in the first place wasn't an actual text file but a binary file with some UTF-16 in the middle. This "od" tool will help a lot, thank you.